# What python library to use for non-blocking audio I/O on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, audio, numpy, pip

I would like to read and write audio in Python. I tried PyAudio and audiolab, but both only do blocking audio I/O (i.e. you can't do anything else while they play or record).

Now I would need a library that does non-blocking audio I/O on OSX. Bonus points for LGPL/BSD license, compatibility with pip and playback of numpy arrays!

Comment: Any reason for not simply using threads?

Comment: Threads still don't enable continuous audio output since the audio thread still has to stop playing to push new samples to the audio queue.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with "pip" and "numpy"? Although numpy might tangentially relate to the question, I can't imagine why pip does.

Comment: @gotgenes: I think the last sentence is saying that quite clearly. If possible, I want to be able to install it using pip.

Comment: @BastiBechtold: Understood. Do you feel like your question is about pip, *itself*, though? The "pip" tag indicates, "I am a question about pip."

Comment: @gotgenes: I can't find any item in the FAQ that would define a tag in that way. But of course, this is not a 'question about pip'. More like, 'involving pip in some way'. Do you think it needs changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few days ago, I submitted a patch to [pyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) that enables non blocking audio I/O there.

As of Version 0.2.7, the patch is in. Now non-blocking I/O is officially supported by PyAudio.

Comment: About a year ago, I decided to play around with CFFI a bit. This developed into [PySoundCard](https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundCard), which is a more pythonic portaudio wrapper than PyAudio. I would recommend everyone to check out PySoundCard (and it's brother, PySoundFile).

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Pygame?  It's a very comprehensive wrapper around the SDL library and it will allow you to queue up and play music while doing other processing.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html

It also has routines for converting between pygame Sound objects and Numpy arrays.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sndarray.html

Comment: Man, what a pain to build this thing on OSX! I don't really like that Pygame provides next to no control about how the audio is being played. Though not strictly necessary for my current project, Pygame lacks support for channel mapping, multichannel playback and recording, which I would like to have available. It is amazingly fun to work with, though. Must be awesome for game development! Thank you for the tip!